# C# - combobox selected value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using this code in order to add some value the database.

```
string cs = "Data Source=CODRINMA\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=BusManager; Trusted_Connection=True;";
string insert = "INSERT INTO Autocare (IDAutocar, TipAutocar) VALUES (@IDAutocar, @TipAutocar)";

try
{
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
     {
         con.Open();
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, con);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDAutocar", txtID.Text);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipAutocar", cmbTip.SelectedValue);
         int valoare = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         con.Close();
         MessageBox.Show(valoare + "Autocarul a fost adaugat cu succes!");
      }
}

catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show(er.Message); }
```

On this line --> `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipAutocar", cmbTip.SelectedValue);` I would like that the user to select a value provided by the combobox (values that was completed in another form) and when I press the button to insert the value in the DB, i'm having this error --

> The parametrized query '(@IDAutocar nvarchar(1), @TipAutocar nvarchar(4000)) INSERT INTO A 'expects the parameter '@TipAutocar', which was not supplied.

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: i guess you have not bound your `ComboBox` to a DataSource... so try `cmbTip.SelectedItem` instead.

Comment: Have you checked if there is a `SelectedValue`?

Comment: Did you debug your code and what is `cmbTip.SelectedValue` exactly?

Comment: I would also suggest using cmd.Parameters.Add and than use cmd.Parameters["name"].Value.

Comment: Did you give `cmbTip` a `DataSource`, a `ValueMember` and a `DisplayMember` ?

Comment: I agree you should debug and look if `cmbTip.SelectedValue` has the expected value. Given the exception you get I'm pretty sure it's `null`.

Comment: @codrin Afrasinei is there value is binding in the ` cmbTip` What you write code for binding ` cmbTip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipAutocar",cmbTip.GetItemText(cmbTip.SelectedItem));
```

Answer (score 0):

SelectedValue does not return a string. You have to use :

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipAutocar", cmbTip.SelectedValue.ToString());
```